# What approach should I use when advertisingIdentifier is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

According to apple docs, sometimes it happens that the method `[ASIdentifierManager sharedManager].advertisingIdentifier` can return a `nil` value and I really need this value in my app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ASIdentifierManager/advertisingIdentifier

> If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens,
>   for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user
>   has unlocked the device.

How long should I wait? What approach should I use in this case? Maybe keep trying to get the advertisingIdentifier until it is available? Or should I tell the user to try to restart the app? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Any update on the solution you used?
What I don't understand is that when using swift, the advertisingIdentifier type is not optional, what means that the value is never nil (we can even not test if it's nil!)

Answer (score 0):

You should manually create UUID and should save it in preferences.

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kApplicationUUIDKey];
if (!UUID) {
    CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    UUID = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuid);
    CFRelease(uuid);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:UUID forKey:kApplicationUUIDKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea for this question - it's an answer for when the advertisingID is unavailable because of user preferences.

Comment: personally i am facing the issue, my app is crashing coz advertisingIdentifier is giving nil value, so i am going to use:

    NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

Answer (score 0):

You can effectively get a notification when the user unlocks the phone using protected files and listening for [applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable:)